# Finding a CPU's Capacitive Load

Tags: power, capacitance

I am very very new to the electronic engineering side of things but I am taking a class on Computer Architecture. I have ran into a problem.

Power = Capacitive Load * Voltage ^ 2 * Frequency Switched.

I have a hard time understanding what capacitive load is. Let's say I have a CPU with the following specs.

```
Uses 3.3 Volts
Requires 29.1 Watts
Has a clock rate of 200 Mhz
```

How would I use these three bits of info to find a capacitive load? Can I? I'm not sure if I am going about this correctly. Help is appreciated! :)

Comment: While Dean has already provided the "correct" answer, it's a somewhat strange and unrealistic question. Normally you'd start by modelling the capacitance and use that to work out the dynamic power; then you need to address the fact that not all the CPU switches at once; then you need to consider static leakage power.

Comment: Yeah it is strange. I am working out of a book called Computer Organization and Design. I thought it would be good learning material but honestly they don't explain hardly anything. Questions in the book are very vague at times.

Comment: It's sure an interesting way of looking at things, I remember a very similar question some months back but unlike your question it was very poorly defined so I think it got closed / deleted.

Comment: In simpler times you could empirically determine a processors "capacitance", which was really just the constant that best fit the relationship between power and clock frequency. Modern processors have leaky transistors and the relationship is not so simple.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a simple arranging to resolve the equation for Capacitive load. Like so

\$
\frac{Power}{Voltage^2 \times frequency} = Capacitive Load \$

With the numbers you gave we get:

\$
\frac{29.1}{3.3^2 \times 200*10^6} = 1.33\times 10^{-8}  \mathrm{F} \$

F is farads the unit for capacitance.

I have assumed that the given equation takes power to be in watts.

Comment: should be 200 \cdot 10^6 Hz, not ^3

Comment: Yes it is in Watts. :) Thank you very much. The book I was given doesn't show me anything other than the relative power formula, so I was a bit lost.