# Given the dynamic and static power consumption how does one determine the total power for the capacitive load?

Tags: voltage, power, frequency, cpu, capacitive

I get that the capacitive load is determined which is also indicated by this [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/82908/finding-a-cpus-capacitive-load): 
 $$\frac{Power}{Voltage^2 \times frequency} = Capacitive Load$$

However, I am not sure how power (which is given in Watts) is determined when given both the dynamic and static power consumption and unfortunately my [textbook](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0124077269) doesn't really give any suggestions either. My guess is power would be equal to either dynamic - static or dynamic + static, but I don't which one would be correct, if either are correct, and more importantly why that statement is correct.

Comment: Just an fyi I am an intro Comp Sci student so I don't have background in any Engineering so if possible write my level. :P

Comment: In the title you ask one thing, while your question asks something different. Please fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both dynamic power consumption and static power consumption are consumptions, so the total consumption is the sum of both. AFAIK for modern CPUs the dynamic power consumption dominates at practical frequencies.